# How to draw grid into circle using html5

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, physics, game-physics

I am trying to draw grid into circle using html5 as shown below using paper js:
[image]

But I can't understand, what would be right logic for this solution in javascript. Following my script:

```
for (var _q=0,_qmax=(2*Math.PI),_qstep=(Math.PI/20); _q<_qmax; _q+=_qstep)
        {

            _sx = x+Math.sin(_q)*_radius;
            _sy = y+Math.cos(_q)*_radius;

             var path=new Path();
            path.strokeColor='white';
            path.strokeWidth=2;             
            path.moveTo(_sx,_sy);
            path.lineTo(_sy,_sx);
        }
```

Comment: whats wrong here?? why give negative vote. if knw better, help me.

Comment: please make a snippet. your question could be answered in seconds..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PskkM.jpg . i add image. plz check it.

Answer (score 1):

finally i can understand, what's problem in there. so many people give me negative vote without proper answer. thx to them "make me grow". use the canvas x,y coordinate following structure.

```
_draw_grid:function(_radius,_step,_color, _width)
    {
           var _group=new APP.RADAR.Group();
            for (var _q=0,_qmax=(2*Math.PI),_qstep=(Math.PI/_step); _q<_qmax; _q+=_qstep){
              _sx = APP.POSITION.x+Math.sin(_q)*_radius;
              _sy = APP.POSITION.y+Math.cos(_q)*_radius;

                var path=new APP.RADAR.Path();
                path.strokeColor=_color;
                path.strokeWidth=_width;
                path.moveTo(_sx,APP.POSITION.y*2-_sy);
                path.lineTo(_sx,_sy);
                _group.addChild(path);

            }
            for (var _q=0,_qmax=(2*Math.PI),_qstep=(Math.PI/_step); _q<_qmax; _q+=_qstep){
              _sx = APP.POSITION.x+Math.sin(_q)*_radius;
              _sy = APP.POSITION.y+Math.cos(_q)*_radius;

                var path=new APP.RADAR.Path();
                path.strokeColor=_color;
                path.strokeWidth=_width;
                path.moveTo(APP.POSITION.y*2-_sy,_sx);
                path.lineTo(_sy,_sx);
                _group.addChild(path);

            }
        return _group;
    },
```

Comment: Do you want a regular grid. I think the grid lines will have uneaven spacing here. You might want something like for(x=-rad;x<=rad;x+=step) { ylow = -sqrt(rad*rad-x*x); yhigh = sqrt(rad*rad-x*x); moveTo(x,ylow); lineTo(x,yhigh); } using pythagoras to get the y coordinate.